# How to put hidden parameters and to sent next page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using GridView.
I would like to go next page when these grids are pressed.

I would like to know how to each grid has parameter which would be hidden in grids and sent these parameters for next page.

How can I implement it?

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    childAspectRatio: 2,
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scoresheet()
        ));
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          boxShadow: const [ BoxShadow(blurRadius: 2), ]
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('${snapshot.data[index].game_name}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            Text('')//IF IT COULD BE HIDDEN.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question fully... What is this hidden parameter? If all tiles have a hidden parameter or just some? if some doesn't what is the requirement for  them to send to necxt page?

Comment: I would like each grid has parameter like ID. When I tap one, then each ID sent and next page shows the ID details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How You can pass the data with Navigator:

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),
          ),
        );
```

How you can receive data at new screen:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final Todo todo;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(todo.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.description),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more details [Click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)